# How can I declare pointer to different data types but they will occupy the same amount of space in memory

Tags: c

This is my code

```
int main()
{ 
   char *pchar;
   short *pshort;
   int *pint;
   long *plong;
   float *pfloat;
   double *pdouble;

   pchar = pshort = pint = plong = pfloat = pdouble;
   printf("sizeof *pchar   is = %u\n",sizeof(pchar));
   printf("sizeof *pshort  is = %u\n",sizeof(pshort));
   printf("sizeof *pint    is = %u\n",sizeof(pint));
   printf("sizeof *plong   is = %u\n",sizeof(plong));
   printf("sizeof *pfloat  is = %u\n",sizeof(pfloat));
   printf("sizeof *pdouble is = %u\n",sizeof(pdouble));

   return 0;
}
```

I want each of these pointer variables to point to different data types, but they will occupy the same amount of space in memory. How can I do that?

Comment: and I though pointers themselves take same amount of memory for a fixed environment.

Comment: You most likely either got all `4`'s (on a x86 box) or all `8`'s (on an x86_64) box. All pointers have the same size as discussed above. What you want is `sizeof *pchar`, `sizeof *pshort`, etc...

Comment: Which ones are different?

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic pointer.

> When a variable is declared as being a pointer to type void it is
>   known as a generic pointer. Since you cannot have a variable of type
>   void, the pointer will not point to any data and therefore cannot be
>   dereferenced. It is still a pointer though, to use it you just have to
>   cast it to another kind of pointer first. Hence the term Generic
>   pointer.

This [link](http://www.nongnu.org/c-prog-book/online/x658.html) has an example.

Comment: Don't use "casts" for this, a simple conversion of object pointers from and to `void*` just does fine in C. Casts are evil and should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: void* worked but the problem is all of the pointer data occupy different amount of space in memory how can i make them occupy same amount of space  in memory